# Does Visual Studio Support Editing of Robots.txt?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, search-engine, robots.txt

Any robots.txt revisions applied inside VS2010 save the file with BOM which basically causes Google to reject it with a ['**Syntax not understood**' error](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=28d012e70d5fcdc8&hl=en). There is a [related question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406172/utf-8-without-bom-in-visual-studio-2010) but the "Save With Encoding" option isn't available for text files - even if it were, there should be a solution that just works with CTRL + S rather than having to go the advanced route just to keep BOM out.

I can't believe I'm the the only person experiencing this problem, surely there's a solution?

Comment: robots.txt is a simple plain text file that rarely changes. Any reason you wouldn't want to do this by hand?

Comment: @John: agreed, it rarely changes. But mistakes can be catastrophic for SEO. You don't find it bizarre that one of the most sensitive files for a web app can't be modified in the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an easy fix for this is to have a blank line or a comment as the first line of the file:
http://www.12titans.net/p/robots-txt-bom.aspx

Comment: It worth noting that you can also use the "Advanced Save Options" in the File menu to switch to a BOM-less codepage.

Answer (score 0):

VS adds the BOM to UTF-8 file, but why should your robots.txt file be encoded as UTF-8 anyway?

Since it contains URLs, it should be plain ASCII or ISO-8859-1. If your site URLs contain non-ASCII characters, you have to URL-encode them appropriately. Making the file plain ANSI will save all the BOM hassle.

Also see [robots.txt; What encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816795/robots-txt-what-encoding)